# Save images from fileupload into another project

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am using microsoft visual studio and had created a solution file with 2 projects inside. 
Inside one of the aspx file in project A, I had a file upload control.

When the "upload" button is onclick, it would save the image I uploaded into a folder in Project A as well as a folder in Project B. I am only able to save the image into Project A folder using the below code.

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + filename));
```

But I am unable to save the images into Project B folder. with the code below, it had generate this error: *ImagesFile is a folder inside Project B*

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ImagesFile/" + filename));

Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Desktop\DSC000015.JPG'.
```

Is there anyway that I had access the file path of another project???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is Server.MapPath always gives you a path to inside your web directory. It will never be able to map a path outside your application.

You have two ways to accomplish this task.

1.Save a path in web.config file which should be an absolute path i.e. "c:\users\desktop\" and append the image name to this path.

or

2.You will have to create a page in project 2 which should accept images in post and save in a particular folder. So whenever an image is uploaded in project 1, it in turn, posts it to project 2 which ultimately saves it to a folder mapped inside its directory.

Comment: First method is available only when both your projects are hosted on the same machine. You need the absolute path to the folder of second project's image directory. e.g. c:\inetpub\www\project2\images\ which has to be saved in web.config of first project. This path can be used to save the images when uploaded e.g.FileUpload1.SaveAs(configurationmanager.appsettings["project2folder"] + filename